# ViewBinder's setViewValue with a MatrixCursor instead of a Cursor

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-viewbinder, matrixcursor

I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter with a MatrixCursor to load data from my server into a listview. I want to customize each item using a ViewBinder. I noticed that setViewValue has the following parameters:

```
setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)
```

I tried replacing the Cursor parameter with MatrixCursor but this gives errors as it I have to implement the inherited method.

How can I work this out? I did not post any code because I think of this as a more abstract question. I will post code if necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly did you mean by *I tried replacing the Cursor parameter with MatrixCursor but this gives errors...*?

Comment: This is working fine now. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Ok, but please don't let the question without an answer. Post yourself an answer with the result/solution and then accept it to close it.